find with du -sch and very many files
I have large folder structure and need to get the size of a certain subset. The directories I need to count are defined by having specific subdirectories:
find . \( -iname a -or ... \) -printf "\"%h\"\n" | xargs -- du -sch | sort -rh 

This works fine up to a certain point. But when there are too many folders, I get multiple totals in the result (using echo instead of du with xargs shows that the output is broken up into multiple lines, i.e., calls to du).
This is probably caused by some buffer limits. Is there any way to get around this, so I get only a single total size in the output?

What do you want as your output? Can you provide an example in your question

Yes, please add an example of the expected output. Also, just FYI, instead of the cumbersome "\"foo\"", you can just use single quotes: -printf '"%h"\n'.

Your quoting makes no sense, the output of find doesn't get interpreted by a shell; neither does using \n as separator; you should instead always use \0 zero byte as separator and use xargs with -0; the zero byte can never be part of a file name or path!
Anyways, that might not solve the issue at hand:
Command lines have a maximum length; so having a single call to du with very many parameters might simply be impossible.
If you have GNU coreutils du (you probably do if you're on a fully-fledged Linux, du --version would tell you), you can use du --files0-from= to read the files from a file, or specifically, from standard input, when using - as file name:
find . \( CRITERIA \) -printf '%h\0' | du -sch --files0-from=- | sort -rh

Stéphane points out that it'd make more sense to remove duplicates from the files before they get processed:
find . \( CRITERIA \) -printf '%h\0' | LC_ALL=C sort -zu | du -sch --files0-from=-

LC_ALL=C instructs sort to use the "default English-UNIX locale" for sorting. That's usually a good idea to avoid having different ordering depending on the language of the user.

xargs does its own quote interpretation, so that quoting makes sense assuming file paths don't contain quote characters. Also note the OP seems to want to get the disk usage of directories that contains a file called a, so you may want -printf '%h\0' | LC_ALL=C sort -zu | du --files0-from=- ...

Thanks, fixed that!

In any case, all of -print0, -printf, -h, -z, -0 --files0-from, -iname are GNU extensions (though -print0 and xargs -r0 were added to the 2024 edition of the POSIX standard and -iname/-h are now also found in some non-GNU implementation)

The sort -u is not so much about sorting, more about removing duplicates.

I needed the quotes because some file names contained spaces, without it du did not find them. But using \0 termination and du --files0-from=- works very well. Thanks!

@cheersmate xargs wouldn't care about spaces, by default it only separates by lines. So, the problems wouldn't be spaces but newlines.

@MarcusMüller: xargs by default absolutely does break at unquoted (and unescaped) space; POSIX requires it. All variants I know of have options for newline-only (or as noted null-only in GNU), which is easier than fiddling the quoting, but is not always portable.

I would solve it in TXR Lisp like this. Say that the directories we want to find are characterized by having subdirectories called alpha, beta and gamma:
(let* ((dirs (glob* "**/{alpha,beta,gamma}/"))
       (total 0)
       (sizes (each ((d dirs))
                (ftw (dir-name d)
                     (lambda (path type stat . others)
                       (inc total stat.blocks)
                       nil)))))
  (prinl (* 512 total)))

Because we are using the double star ** and brace expansion, we must use the glob* function; the glob function is a near direct wrapper for the POSIX C library function of the same name; glob* implements the additional features on top of that.
The trailing slash in our glob pattern ensures that only directories are matched; a file or other object named gamma doesn't count.
Once we identify the matching directories, we iterate over their parents (with the help of dir-name), and recursively process each one using ftw, adding up the visited object sizes by multiplying their total block count by 512.
To count duplicate inodes (hard links to the same file) only once:
(let* ((dirs (glob* "**/{alpha,beta,gamma}/"))
       (ihash (hash))
       (total 0)
       (sizes (each ((d dirs))
                (ftw (dir-name d)
                     (lambda (path type stat . others)
                       (when (test-set [ihash stat.ino])
                         (inc total stat.blocks))
                       nil)))))
  (prinl (* 512 total)))

This is necessary not only if there are hard links, but possibly if the same directory comes up more than once. Suppose that we have path/to/gamma and path/to/beta.  Their parent is the same directory; we end up processing it twice. The code could be improved to avoid that, but the inode hash will at least prevent double counting.
